# How to read performance counters on i5, i7 CPUs

Tags: cpu, intel, performancecounter

Modern CPUs have quite a lot of performance counters - http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-system-programming-manual-325384.html how to read them?
I'm interested in cache misses and branch mispredictions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like [PAPI](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/) has very clean API and works just fine on Ubuntu 11.04.
Once it's installed, following app will do what I wanted:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <papi.h>

#define NUM_EVENTS 4

void matmul(const double *A, const double *B,
        double *C, int m, int n, int p)
{
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < p; ++j) {
            double sum = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < n; ++k)
                sum += A[i*n + k] * B[k*p + j];
            C[i*p + j] = sum;
        }
}

int main(int /* argc */, char ** /* argv[] */)
{
    const int size = 300;
    double a[size][size];
    double b[size][size];
    double c[size][size];

    int event[NUM_EVENTS] = {PAPI_TOT_INS, PAPI_TOT_CYC, PAPI_BR_MSP, PAPI_L1_DCM };
    long long values[NUM_EVENTS];

    /* Start counting events */
    if (PAPI_start_counters(event, NUM_EVENTS) != PAPI_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "PAPI_start_counters - FAILED\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    matmul((double *)a, (double *)b, (double *)c, size, size, size);

    /* Read the counters */
    if (PAPI_read_counters(values, NUM_EVENTS) != PAPI_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "PAPI_read_counters - FAILED\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Total instructions: %lld\n", values[0]);
    printf("Total cycles: %lld\n", values[1]);
    printf("Instr per cycle: %2.3f\n", (double)values[0] / (double) values[1]);
    printf("Branches mispredicted: %lld\n", values[2]);
    printf("L1 Cache misses: %lld\n", values[3]);

    /* Stop counting events */
    if (PAPI_stop_counters(values, NUM_EVENTS) != PAPI_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "PAPI_stoped_counters - FAILED\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Tested this on Intel Q6600, it supports up to 4 performance events. Your processor may support more or less.

Comment: PAPI is good stuff. It's cross-platform so it works on most platforms, from x86-Windows to IBM BlueGenes.

Answer (score 6):

What about [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page)? `perf list hw cache` shows 33 different events and the man page shows how to use raw performance counter descriptors.

Answer (score 2):

Performance counters are read with the `RDPMC` insn.

**EDIT:** To add a bit more info, reading performance counters is not very easy and it would take pages upon pages if we are to describe it here, besides it involves  writes to Model Specific Registers, which require privileged instructions. I would instead advise to use ready profilers - oprofile or Intel VTune, which are built upon performance counters.

Comment: It doesn't look that difficult after you mentioned RDPMC. Once priviledged mode for RDPMC is disabled its just 15 lines of code, and Linux 2.6.32 disable it by default. Also there is pretty nice library - http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/software/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a available library that can be used, called perfmon2, http://perfmon2.sourceforge.net/, and documentations are available at http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/perfmon/perfmon.php4 and http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2004/HPL-2004-200R1.html, I am recently digging this lib out, I would post example code as soon as I figure it out~