# A program to calculate Cache Hit and Miss

Tags: c++, caching, cpu-architecture, hit

I have a task to write a software tool that will measure the hit and miss of the different levels of the cache memory (L1, L2, L3).
The program should be writen in c/c++ with which I am comfortable, but have never done anything so low level to the hardware. 
I'm not looking for a solution, just a direction on what tools, libraries and functions can i use.

Comment: Cache management is done in hardware, not by the operating system. As such this is very platform specific, but you can use a library to get around that somewhat. What hardware are you targeting? This question may help (if you're using intel): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091182/how-to-read-performance-counters-on-i5-i7-cpus

Comment: I am using Windows 8 and Intel, I will look at the link you suggested ASAP. Thanks

Comment: Is your program meant to notify you when a cache miss occurs in L1 / L2 / L3 OR is your program meant to measure the penalty of a cache miss in L1 / L2 /L3 ?

Comment: The program iz meant to measure the time of a hit and the time for a miss (the penalty) in the different levels.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for statistics (cache hit ratio) when running a binary on a hypothetical cache configuration? If so, check out [Cachegrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html). There's an implementation section on that page that links to a PhD with some details. It could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

There are several open-source simulators which implement cache hierarchy to a reasonable detail (E.g., [MArss86](http://marss86.org/~marss86/index.php/Home), Simics, [M5](http://www.m5sim.org/Main_Page), and actually several others). Note exactly clear from your question what your needs are. Please google for them - I am sure you will find many.

And, There is a well-known simulator for cache access modelling - [CACTI](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~rajeev/cacti6/). These should give you some ideas on how to start with your own implementation.

The advantage to using these tools is that they allow you to also perform some architectural space exploration (vary parameters / configs and see their impact)